# X509Authentication with Java and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, x509certificate

In my application I'm trying to implement authentication using X509 certificates

I found default solutions provided by the Spring Security framework as follows:

- [X509AuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/x509/X509AuthenticationFilter.java)
- [X509PrincipalExtractor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/ad907457eeeee46da101215f5408d3cd98de4881/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/x509/X509PrincipalExtractor.java)
- [X509AuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/main/spring-ws-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/x509/X509AuthenticationProvider.java)
- [X509AuthoritiesPopulator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/main/spring-ws-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/x509/X509AuthoritiesPopulator.java)

Given how much I know about Spring Security, the purpose of these classes and interfaces is as follows:

`X509AuthenticationFilter` is responsible for intercepting the HTTP request, creating an authRequest token (of type `X509AuthenticationToken`) in `doFilter()` method and initializing the authentication process by delegating the token to the authManager. The authManager later delegates the authentication job to the `X509AuthenticationProvider`

The main goal of the `X509AuthenticationProvider` is to perform the authentication by extracting the UserDetails using `X509AuthoritiesPopulator` and setting it to the new `X509AuthenticationToken` that is later set in `SecurityContext`. After the new token has been set, the process is finished.

`X509PrincipalExtractor` is an interface, implementation of which should return a DN (Distinguished Name) from a certificate. However, it's not clear to me where it should be used. In my application I use it to get the DN and based on the DN I return a UserDetails instance inside `X509AuthoritiesPopulator`.

My questions are the following:

1. Where should I use the `X509PrincipalExtractor`? I put this interface inside my `X509AuthoritiesPopulator` to get the UserDetails instance based the returned string value of DN. Is that correct?
2. Why is the `X509PrincipalExtractor` used in the default `X509AuthenticationFilter` provided by spring security in the method `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal()`?
3. What's the point of the method `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal()` anyway? What it should look like in my class? I found it in the `doAuthenticate()` method in the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`, but from what I can gather, just an `X509Certificate` instance is enough to create an `X509AuthenticationToken`, there's no need for principle. Am I missing something?

My doAuthenticate() method is below:

```
private void doAuthenticate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    // why would I need principle? I found this in the doAuthenticate() of AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter 
    Object principal = getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(request);
    X509Certificate credentials = getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(request);
    try
    {
        X509AuthenticationToken authRequest = new X509AuthenticationToken(credentials);
        authRequest.setDetails(super.getAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        Authentication authResult = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException e)
    {
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, e);
    }
}
```

4. In `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` there's a method called `principalChanged()`. How come a principle can change? The certificate is always static and simply can't be modified.

Comment: In your code you are not using principal - but in the spring github they use it:                          
  if (principal == null) {
   this.logger.debug("No pre-authenticated principal found in request");
   return;
  }

Comment: In their code they also only get the credentials if the principal is not null - in their code they say (for preAuthCredentials): "Override to extract the credentials (if applicable) from the current request. Should not return null for a valid principal, though some implementations may return a dummy value."

Comment: From what I gathered - isn't the point of this "preAuthentication" stuff when "it is assumed that the principal has already been authenticated by an external system." - so I'm guessing this is for when you have a separate authentication provider right?

Comment: Yes, the authentication provider is my own `X509AuthenticationProvider` that takes the `X509AuthenticationToken` and does the actual authentication by creating a new `X509AuthenticationToken` that's returned by the `authenticate()` method

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting the concept of pre-authentication but could you please clarify how to return "a dummy value"? Just a null in the `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal()` method?

Comment: If you look in [X509AuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/x509/X509AuthenticationFilter.java) they have a method that overrides `getPreAuthPrincipal` - which just extracts the token from the request. I think the point of preauthorisation is that the request should already contain the information as its "externally authenticated" as I gathered - it could be a "dummy" object just means it shouldn't be null I think, maybe You can just have an "Object" with no information.

Comment: In their [X509AuthenticationFilter]() you will see that they do this check at line 36: `return (cert != null) ? this.principalExtractor.extractPrincipal(cert) : null;` - which means they return a principal if the certificate exists (and thus the principal should exists), therefore I think that `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal()` method returns null ONLY when the user wasn't preauthenticated - as they are missing the certificate. I think this makes sense right?